# conda installing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

i am having issue in installing the tensorflow package to the conda (conda 4.5.12)installtion on windows 64bit version.

conda create -n tensorflow
Solving environment: done

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions'))"))

I am not using proxy server.
And i tried setting ssl_verify no

conda config --set ssl_verify no

so my .condarc has no othere entries than ssl_verify no

I did google the issue and pretty much tried all the suggested pointers.

Can some one give me some pointers on what could be the issue.
PS : I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the anaconda package.

Looks like two packets are sent and one is received.
The client appears to be terminating the session:
tcp-rst-from-client—The client sent a TCP reset to the server

Not sure why client should send terminate request.